# AWS EC2 ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

Had to restart an EC2 instance due to heavy load. When it came back up, I could not longer SSH into it. A `-vvv` of the ssh command produced this output, but I'm not sure how to interpret this... (IP obfuscated)

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/ecomevo/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "xx.xx.xx.xx" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/ecomevo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ecomevo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ecomevo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ecomevo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ecomevo/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ecomevo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ecomevo/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ecomevo/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
```

I checked permissions on ssh related files, but not sure if that is the problem:

```
$ ls -alF .ssh/
total 56
drwx------ 11 ecomevo staff   374 Jul 15 12:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 20 ecomevo staff   680 Nov 26 18:45 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 ecomevo staff  6148 May 25  2015 .DS_Store
-rw-------  1 ecomevo staff   299 Jul 15 12:05 config
-rw-------  1 ecomevo staff   179 Jun 25  2015 environment
-rw-------  1 ecomevo staff  3326 May 15  2015 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 ecomevo staff   750 May 15  2015 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 ecomevo staff 17747 Oct 13 12:21 known_hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 ecomevo staff  2786 May 19  2015 known_hosts.old
```

Restarting my Mac did not fix the issue as I've seen suggested in other posts.

Comment: What is the full command-line you are issuing? It looks like `ssh` is checking lots of keys that were added via `ssh-add`, but they're not the right key. Do you have the keypair used when the instance was launched? If so, try `ssh -i <keypair.pem> ...`.

Comment: JohnRotenstein It's simply `ssh forge@xx.xx.xx.xx -vvv` Everyone is granted access thru their personal ssh keys. I don't have the original keypair.

Comment: Why the vote to close? Please at least comment before voting to close so I can improve the post.

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, help support the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).

Comment: Your ssh connection is being immediately closed from the server side. This is a common question and it isn't really on topic for stackoverflow. Searching for "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" will produce several similar questions on [su], [sf], and [unix.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typically three reasons why you might be unable to connect:

- The instance is **unaccessible**, due to VPC or Security Group configuration. However, you are getting `connection established`, so this isn't the case.
- The **wrong username** is being used
- The **wrong keypair** is being used, either on the local end or the remote end

If you think everything is correct, but it still isn't working, then you could copy another public key into the EC2 instance (into the user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file). If you can access the server via another user, then they could copy the key for you. If you cannot access the server, then:

- **Stop** the instance
- Detach the **boot disk**
- **Attach** it to another EC2 instance
- Copy the public key to the desired location
- Detach the disk and **reattach** it to the original instance
- **Start** the original instance
- SSH using the **new keypair**

Comment: This is only affecting me and no other users. I tried removing my public key from the instance and added it back, but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Wrong username or wrong keypair wouldn't produce an error during ssh_exchange_identification. At that point, the client hasn't tried authenticating yet.

Comment: It appears my IP was blocked on the server. Had someone remove it from `hosts.deny`. Within seconds, my IP is blocked again by the server even if I didn't try to login again. All login attempts result in `operation timed out` now unless I do so from a completely different IP than my office IP. What could cause this?

Comment: [denyhosts keeps adding back my IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225300/denyhosts-keeps-adding-back-my-ip) & [Denyhosts keeps adding my IP address to hosts.deny](http://superuser.com/questions/174162/denyhosts-keeps-adding-my-ip-address-to-hosts-deny) & [Whitelisting An IP Address With “DenyHosts”](https://blackflag.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/whitelisting-an-ip-address-with-denyhosts/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Always `operation timed out` even after dealing with denyhosts. Whitelisted IP in `hosts.allowed` and `/var/lib/denyhosts/hosts-valid`, plus removed from `hosts.deny` and `/var/lib/denyhosts/hosts-restricted`. Even went so far as to disable denyhosts service entirely but didn't fix. I checked `iptables` and found many entries of my IP there. Removing them fixed the last of the connection issues. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

On my test server on EC2 I observer the same issue and received the below error:
"ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"
This happened after running some scans for vulnerability assessments...
The first thing I did was to reboot the EC2 instance however that didn't fix the issue,then I stopped the server and started back again which fixed the Issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Even I tried launching through `EC2 instance connect` which never worked.

After re-booting my instance, I found out that my `cron` jobs was not able to allocate memory in my `t2.medium` instance. Looks like some jobs occupied larger memory than expected.

`anacron[21604]: Can't fork: Cannot allocate memory`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I resolved it by:

Stopping the instance then starting the instance.